# rectangle lines plot in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I would like to make a plot with matplotlib in python with rectangle lines likes this one:

[image: Rectangle line plot example]

Sadly I have no idea how to call this kind of plot (I photoshoped this one together, it's kind of like a bar plot but rotated by 90 degrees), therefore my google search is a lost case. My dataset is like this:

```
   y   x
  1.0 1.0
  0.6 2.3
  0.3 3.3
  0.1 1.4
 -0.4 2.1
 -0.6 3.8
 -0.8 0.9
 -1.0
```

I already put `x` and `y` into two lists of variables. Basically the `x` value should be drawn in between the current and the next `y` value (compare the picture and the values in the example).

Comment: This looks a lot like a line chart to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `"steps-"` linestyle for plotting, (`"steps-pre"`, `"steps-post"`, `"steps-mid"`). Those determine whether the coordinates are meant to denote the beginning, the middle and the end of the line.

```
step = plt.plot(y,x, linestyle="steps-pre")
```

Some complete example:

```
u = u"""y   x
  1.0 1.0
  0.6 2.3
  0.3 3.3
  0.1 1.4
 -0.4 2.1
 -0.6 3.8
 -0.8 0.9
 -1.0 0"""

import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y,x = np.genfromtxt(io.StringIO(u),skip_header=1, unpack=True)

step = plt.plot(x,y, linestyle="steps-pre")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah the linestyle steps was exactly what I was looking for. I needed to fix the data however with `x.append(x[-1])` to get rid of the line at -1

Answer (score 2):

You should try `matplolib.path`, Try the following code

```
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Path = mpath.Path
path_data = [
    (Path.MOVETO, (1.58, -2.57)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (0.35, -1.1)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (-1.75, 2.0)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (0.375, 2.0)),
    (Path.LINETO, (0.85, 1.15)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (2.2, 3.2)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (3, 0.05)),
    (Path.CURVE4, (2.0, -0.5)),
    (Path.CLOSEPOLY, (1.58, -2.57)),
    ]

codes, verts = zip(*path_data)
path = mpath.Path(verts, codes)

# plot control points and connecting lines
x, y = zip(*path.vertices)
line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'go-')

ax.grid()
ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

You will get a basic understanding of how path works and then modify your vertices to plot your own graph. For more info, please refer to the following link:
https://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#module-matplotlib.path

Comment: Do I interpret it right, that I would need to rewrite the dataset into the path code for this? If yes, this is not useful for me, as I have many datasets of unknown sizes. I was more looking for something which makes use of a real plot function

Comment: I thought you were gonna draw some complex graphs just one time. In the case that you have to rewrite x and y many times. @Jason 's answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `plt.plot`, you could also add extra vertices. So instead of:

```
x = [1.0, 2.3, 3.3, 1.4, 2.1, 3.8, 0.9]
y = [1.0, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, -0.4, -0.6, -0.8]
```

Do

```
new_x = [1.0, 1.0, 2.3, 2.3, 3.3, 3.3, 1.4, 1.4, 2.1, 2.1, 3.8, 3.8, 0.9]
new_y = [1.0, 0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, -0.4, -0.4, -0.6, -0.6, -0.8, -0.8]
```

giving you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(new_x, new_y)
```

[image: Plot]

Of course, you might notice that we're just repeating the values of `x` twice (with the last value removed) and `y` twice (with the first value removed), so an easy way to convert `x` to `new_x` and `y` to `new_y` with pure Python is:

```
new_x = [a for a in x for _ in range(2)][:-1]
new_y = [a for a in y for _ in range(2)][1:]
```

It would be even cleaner using `itertools` or `np.repeat`.

Comment: That solution works nicely. Just a curious question: How does the "_" fits in? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: Underscore is actually a valid variable name. Usually, it's used for a variable that doesn't hold any significance and won't be used later. For example, if I'm trying to loop 3 times, I could do `for i in range(2)` but it's possible that my code never uses `i`, so it might be cleaner to just do `for _ in range (2)`. Another useful case is if a function returns multiple things and I don't care about one of it's return values: `x, _ = returns_tuple_size_2`. In this case, I might care about the first thing returned but not the second thing returned so I assign it's value to `_`.